# EventListener function in parent class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, event-listener

I have class ShowCase that inherite from my class ContentMC (that inherite from MovieClip).
In the class ShowCase I have an EventListner that calls a function in the parent class ContentMC. But I get an error that says "Access of undefined property restoreMenuItem".

This is my eventlistner in ShowCase.as.

```
showcaseItem.addEventListener("CONTENTMCCLOSED", restoreMenuItem);
```

Here I get the error, it doesn't find the function restoreMenuItem.

The function restoreMenuItem is in ContenMC and looks like this.

```
public function restoreMenuItem(evt:Event):void
        {

}
```

How do I call this function that's in the parent?

Thanks, Vincent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **super** statement.

```
showcaseItem.addEventListener("CONTENTMCCLOSED", super.restoreMenuItem);
```